# How to retrieve hadoop job configuration based on job id that is currently running?

Tags: hadoop

Is there any way to retrieve job configuration (some property from the configuration) if I know job id?

Basically, what I'm doing is checking if there are any running jobs at the moment and then I want to check if some value for property exists in any of currently running jobs?

Part of the code to retrieve currently running jobs:

```
    JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(conf);
    JobClient client = new JobClient(jobConf);
    JobStatus[] status = client.getAllJobs();
    for (int i = 0; i< status.length; i++)
    {
        if (!status[i].isJobComplete())
        {
        JobID jobid = status[i].getJobID();
        System.out.println(jobid.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the configuration of running jobs in the jobtracker, which usually runs on port 50030.