# Propagating custom configuration values in Hadoop

Tags: java, properties, configuration, hadoop, mapreduce

Is there any way to set and (later) get a custom configuration object in Hadoop, during Map/Reduce?

For example, assume an application that preprocesses a large file and determines dynamically some characteristics related to the file. Furthermore, assume that those characteristics are saved in a custom Java object (e.g., a `Properties` object, but not exclusively, since some may not be strings) and are subsequently necessary for each of the map and of the reduce jobs.

How could the application "propagate" this configuration, so that each mapper and reducer function can access it, when needed?

One approach could be to use the `set(String, String)` method of the `JobConf` class and, for instance, pass the configuration object serialized as a `JSON` string via the second parameter, but this may be too much of a hack and then the appropriate `JobConf` instance must be accessed by each `Mapper` and `Reducer` anyway (e.g., following an approach like the one suggested in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696773/how-to-retrieve-hadoop-job-configuration-based-on-job-id-that-is-currently-runni)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, if you have a `Properties` object containing every property you need in your M/R job, you simply need to write the content of the `Properties` object to the Hadoop `Configuration` object. For example, something like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Properties params = getParameters(); // do whatever you need here to create your object
for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    String propName = (String)entry.getKey();
    String propValue = (String)entry.getValue();
    conf.set(propName, propValue);
}
```

Then inside your M/R job, you can use the `Context` object to get back your `Configuration` in both the mapper (the `map` function) or the reducer (the `reduce` function), like this:

```
public void map(MD5Hash key, OverlapDataWritable value, Context context)
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    String someProperty = conf.get("something");
    ....
}
```

Note that when using the `Configuration` object, you can also access the `Context` in the `setup` and `cleanup` methods, useful to do some initialization if needed.

Also it's worth mentioning you could probably directly call the `addResource` method from the `Configuration` object to add your properties directly as an `InputStream` or a file, but I believe this has to be an XML configuration like the regular Hadoop XML configs, so that might just be overkill.

**EDIT**: In case of non-String objects, I would advise using serialization: You can serialize your objects, and then convert them to Strings (probably encode them for example with Base64 as I'm not sure what would happen if you have unusual characters), and then on the mapper/reducer side de-serialize the objects from the Strings you get from the properties inside `Configuration`.

Another approach would be to do the same serialization technique, but instead write to HDFS, and then add these files to the `DistributedCache`. Sounds a bit overkill, but this would probably work.

Comment: This is fine if all the properties are strings. In my use case, some are not, they are (rather complex) custom Java objects that are needed for both the map and the reduce parts. But +1 anyway for the answer. :-)

Comment: @PNS Well if you want to pass non-string object, you could always serialize your objects before to convert the to Strings and pass these strings to the `Configuration`, and then in the mapper/reducer de-serialize the objects. I don't think there's any native way to pass objects around like this. You could probably also serialize the object into a file and put it in HDFS and then get this file with the `DistributedCache` probably.

Comment: Yes, serialization seems necessary anyway, since MapReduce is a distributed application.

Comment: it is a very good idea to encode serialized strings with Base64. Special symbols like *, ' , " etc. can cause job failure.