# How to set objects in Hadoop configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to set an object in `Configuration`

`conf.set("test",myobject)`

But it doesnt exist.

How to set an object in `Configuration` and retrieve the same object value in `Mapper`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly set objects in hadoop configuration. You need to serialize the object, convert it into a string and then set it in the hadoop configuration object. Only then you can make it available for the mappers to use it.

This custom configuration was already discussed here.[custom hadoop configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971825/propagating-custom-configuration-values-in-hadoop)

Comment: Ok satya Inorder to access that object value we need to deserialize back to object right.As i need to get the value as the same object back not as a string. Actually i went through that link previously ..But did nt understood completely:(